# Making a Symmetrical UV Map Asymmetric

Tags: texturing, uv, mirror

I am a beginner to Blender trying to edit a model with existing UV maps and textures.  The model is symmetrical, and each mirrored vertex shares the same UV space.  I would like to make it so each vertex has its own space (and can be textured asymmetrically). I would like to keep the shape of the current map so I can simply duplicate and edit the current texture.

[image: The model]

[image: UV Map for the sweatshirt]

First, I struggled to find out how to select only one half of the mesh, as using box select on the UV map selects both the top vertex and the mirrored one beneath.

If I click on a vertex in the center of my model, I am able to select the entire side using Select > Side of Active.  The problem is, it looks like the center vertices are shared and "folded" in the UV map.  I cannot drag this side to a new space without the edge vertices stretching across the map.

[image]

Is there any easy way to achieve what I am trying to accomplish here without re-unwrapping the UV map?